# Clearing SSL State on IE via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

While working help desk, users often have certificate errors that can be fixed by running an executable and clearing the SSL state via the "Clear SSL State" button within the content tab of IE.

I'm creating a PowerShell script that will perform these tasks on the user computer remotely. Are there PowerShell commands that can accomplish the same tasks that this button does on IE?

I'm having trouble finding out where the SSL cache is actually stored. If I can figure out the functions this button performs then maybe I can recreate them in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/450014/clearmytracksbyprocess-all-options

I BELIEVE it's process #8

Also use

```
invoke-command -computername usersPChostname {rundll32 command}
```